# Is the band structure of an electronic crystal always symmetric around the center of the Brillouin zone?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, electronic-band-theory

What are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions that lead to the band structure of an electronic crystal being symmetric around the center of the Brillouin zone? What symmetries of the Hamiltonian will lead to such a symmetric band structure?

I'm specifically interested in the inversion $\mathcal P$ and  time-reversal $\mathcal T$ symmetries and whether their existence lead to a symmetric band structure and why. 
For example, If we have time-reversal symmetry $[\mathcal H,\mathcal{T}]=0$, then it is necessary that the states $\psi(\mathbf k, \uparrow)$ and $\mathcal{T}\psi(\mathbf k, \uparrow)=\psi^*(-\mathbf k ,\downarrow)$ have the same energies. Does it mean the band structure has to be symmetric around $k=0$? If not, does [Kramers' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers_theorem) (that say all states must be at least doubly degenerate in a TR-symmetric spin-$1/2$ system) still hold if the band is not symmetric and therefore $E(k)\neq E(-k)?$ (I think yes, because the spin degeneracy guarantees a two-fold degeneracy)

(As a side question, would anything be different in case of a *photonic* crystal, for which there is no Kramers' theorem?)

Comment: The Bloch functions which define the electronic structure have the symmetries of the lattice. So, what are the symmetries of the lattice?

Comment: @JonCuster The question is what symmetries lead to $E(\mathbf k)=E(-\mathbf{k})$. And I'm specifically interested in TR symmetry.

Comment: This might be trivial. But, when both time reversal invariance ($\mathcal{T}$) and parity ($\mathcal{P}$) are symmetries of the Hamiltonian ($\hat{\mathcal{H}}$), we will have four fold degeneracy in principle (suppose we have an eigenstate $\Psi(\vec{r})$, then $\mathcal{T}\Psi(\vec{r})$, $\mathcal{P}\Psi(\vec{r})$ and $\mathcal{PT}\Psi(\vec{r})$ are all degenerate unless the eigenstate itself is symmetric).